# iPhone : Unable to create Object of File

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

i am trying to call method of one file from another file.

For this, I am creating another files object and for that importing .h file.

While importing the file I am only able to see .h file where for the other files I can see all files(.h,.m,.xib).

```
#import "FirstView.h"

FirstView *first = [FirstView alloc] init];
```

But It does not allowing me to create object of that file and even it is not showing any error or warning.

what should I do ?

Comment: try deleting build folder and cleaning the build. This should help you.

Comment: @Jennis : i have already tried that but it does not work

Comment: So you mean to say it does not even gives error for syntax also ?

Comment: Strange, because it should throw error like "expected ; before init". Try repeating above steps like cleaning build/deleting build folder after closing xcode once. May be  issue of Xcode

Comment: does your FirstView.m belong to the current target you're compiling ?

Comment: also, could you be more precised about “But It does not allowing me to create object”. does the app crash ? maybe everything is fine and your FirstView is at fault ;)

Comment: Its strange but I have restarted my Xcode4 and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket in your code:

```
#import "FirstView.h"

FirstView *first = [[FirstView alloc] init];
```